# Bash working on command line but not in perl script

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I have a set of .csv files that I'm trying to clean up. Each has data like this:

```
x0,"","",""
x1,123,456,789
x2,123,456,789
x3,123,456,789
-,"","",""
x4,123,456,789
[space],____,____,____
x5,123,456,789
x6,===,====,======
x7,---,--------=--,-------
```

I want to delete all lines that are not xn,###,###,###, so in this example, it would be lines 1, 5, 7, 9, and 10. In the cygwin command line, I type the following commands 1 by 1:

```
    sed -i '/"",""/d' *.csv
    sed -i '/___/d' *.csv
    sed -i '/---/d' *.csv
    sed -i '/===/d' *.csv
```

and these all work. However, when I try to put them TOGETHER into a perl script (the rest of my code is in perl, they fail:

```
    system("sed -i '/"",""/d' *.csv");
    system("sed -i '/___/d' *.csv");
    system("sed -i '/---/d' *.csv");
    system("sed -i '/===/d' *.csv");
```

and I get the result:

> String found where operator expected at test1.pl line 1, near ""sed -i '/"",""
>
> (Missing operator before ","?)
>
> String found where operator expected at test1.pl line 1, near "",""/d' *.csv""
>
> (Missing operator before "/d' *.csv"?)
>
> syntax error at test1.pl line 1, near ""sed -i '/"",""

I notice all work except that first command -- is there something special about `""` in sed? Any help would be appreciated! A simpler solution is welcome as well!

Comment: You can't put double quotes inside double quotes that way (first command).

Comment: Why are you calling sed from within perl? It would be a much better idea to perform these substitutions using native perl functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rest of your script is in Perl, I would strongly suggest replacing your calls to sed with a native implementation.

For example, the replacements you have made using sed could be replaced with something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file (glob '*.csv') {
    open my $in, '<', $file;        
    my @lines;
    while (<$in>) {
        next if /"",""/;
        next if /___/;
        next if /---/;
        next if /===/;
        push @lines, $_;
    }
    close $in;

    # this will overwrite your files!
    # change $file to something else to test
    open my $out, '>', $file;
    print $out $_ for @lines;
}
```

This loops through each file ending in `.csv`, reading each line. It skips any lines that match one of the patterns (you could do this using a single regex with `|` between each pattern if you wanted but I left it the same as your calls to sed). It pushes any remaining lines to an array. It then reopens the input file for writing and prints the array.

Granted, it's slightly longer in terms of numbers of lines but it saves you having to use `system` to call external commands when Perl is more than capable. It also means that each file is only opened once, rather than once per substitution as in your original code.

Comment: You could probably use a regex such as `m/^x\d,\d+,\d+,\d+$/` to look for the lines that exactly match the `xn,###,###,###` lines that are required, with various tweaks to make if the rules require, for example, one or more digits after the `x` (rather than exactly one as shown), or exactly three digits in the other groups (rather than one or more as shown).

Comment: @Jonathan I intentionally left the patterns as they were to make it clearer how they fit into the script but I agree, it would almost certainly be possible to improve on them, perhaps by whitelisting lines as opposed to skipping ones that don't match as you say. Of course, it depends on the diversity of the input and the OP's requirement.

Comment: @Tom Fenech: Thanks for your help. This is definitely a better solution -- I'm rather new to Perl (and programming in general) so I tend to shy away from using it at times... is there any way to easily get rid of a particular character in the while loop? On the last line of these files, a "-" precedes the first string, and I'm trying to get rid of it without the help of sed. This string is "-TOTAL BE". Right now I have inserted the following, but it doesn't seem to be working: 

`my $str2 = "-TOTAL BE"; 
    while (<$in>) {
        $str2 =~ s/-//g;
        next if /"",""/;` etc. etc.

Comment: @Justin you could add a line like `s/^-(?=TOTAL BE)//;`, which would match a `-` at the start of the line followed by `TOTAL BE` and remove it. By default, the substitution will be applied to `$_`, which in the context of the loop, is the line that is currently being read.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the double quotes inside the `sed` argument are ending the Perl string. You need to escape them

```
system("sed -i '/`"`",`"`"/d' *.csv");
```

Or you can use `q(...)`.

```
system(q(sed -i '/"",""/d' *.csv));
```

BTW, you can give multiple commands to `sed`, so you don't have to run it multiple times.

```
system(q(sed -i -e '/"",""/d' -e '/___/d' -e '/---/d' -e '/===/d' *.csv"));
```

or you can use a regular expression with alternation to match all the patterns at once.

```
system(q(sed -i -e '/"",""\\|___\\|---/\\|===/d' *.csv"));
```

Comment: 'Twould be better to use `q(…)` since there's no expansion desired?  But better still not to use `sed` at all; Perl was designed as a `sed`-killer.  That's why there's (still) `s2p` for converting `sed` to Perl.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just realized the same thing.

Comment: If this is just one small step in an overall perl script, rewriting the whole thing in perl might be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

use the escape character `\` to make the interpreter understand that the (", *, .) inside the sed command is not same as Perl's (", *, .)  rather it should consider them as string pattern for sed command.

```
    system("sed -i '/\"\",\"\"/d' \*\.csv");
    system("sed -i '/___/d' \*\.csv");
    system("sed -i '/---/d' \*\.csv");
    system("sed -i '/===/d' \*\.csv");
```